# Referencing key inside of value of another key of a document

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a collection of documents stored in mongodb with each document structured like this:

```
{
    id : <value>
    owner:
        {
            user_id : <value>
            ...
        }
    ...
}
```

Now I want to build a pipeline using pymongo to count the top 3 users belonging to most documents. How do I reference the `user_id` key when building the pipeline?

Comment: `document['owner']['user_id']`?

Comment: @Shiva unfortunately this works outside of the pipeline creation, but inside the pipeline it's a bit different

Comment: By different you mean, the structure changes, like `user_id` is inside another object? I don't clearly understand what do you mean by pipeline creation.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what exactly you need... Anything you've tried already?